# Only getting the first character of the array element

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Can someone help me to figure out why i'm only getting the first character on array element when I insert to database.

My data is coming from checkboxes, then when submitted the data looks like this:

```
array ( 0 => 'Water Sealed', 1 => 'Open Pit', 2 => 'None', )   //$toilet_arr
```

here's my code:

```
if (count($toilet_arr)) {
   foreach($toilet_arr as $row):
   $data = array("hof_id"=>$last_id,"toilet_type"=>$row['toiletType']);
   $this->db->insert('toilet_tbl',$data);
   endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Unclear question.

Comment: This can be a result of targeting a string's 0 index.  `echo "foo"[0];` gives `f`.

Comment: When I print_r() the array it shows the full string, but when i successfully inserted in into database, the 1st character was only stored on the table. W only for what supposed to as Water.

Comment: Perhaps a `var_export` of your `$toilet_arr` could help here, and your toilet_tbl schema.

Comment: Assuming `$toilet_arr` has the correct data, please update your question to include the results from the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE toilet_tbl`

Comment: @fyrye data stored on array was not coming from database. it's coming from checkboxes form.

Comment: I was implying that your table definition maybe the cause of the resulting value saved to the table. Hence i said the `$toilet_arr `is assumed to have the desired data. Please run the `SHOW CREATE TABLE toilet_tbl` query and update your question with the results.

Comment: If `$toilet_arr` is as described in your question, there is no index `toiletType`, it should just be `$row`. But this doesn't explain how a `W` is being inserted. Right now it's looking like we won't be able to reproduce your issue with the details you have provided us.

Comment: This is now OK. Thanks to @Leena Patel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your array the foreach loop should look like this

```
$toilet_arr = array ( 0 => 'Water Sealed', 1 => 'Open Pit', 2 => 'None' );

if (count($toilet_arr)) {
   foreach($toilet_arr as $row) {
      $data = array("hof_id"=>$last_id,"toilet_type"=>$row);
      $this->db->insert('toilet_tbl',$data);
    }
}
```

This should insert values as they are if the problem still persists check the length in your database for column `toilet_type`. You need to set `varchar(250)` for column `toilet_type`

Comment: You save my day. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Bergin There are chances that error can be related to database. As the data was inserting but only the First character. as the OP said The array was returning full data before insert though it was inserting only first character so there are high chances of database length

Comment: @LeenaPatel the column character length was also what I was eluding to. still don't know how `W` was being inserted if the `$toilet_arr` is that structure. Since php should have displayed an `unknown index "toiletType"` error, and inserted `NULL`.

Comment: @fyrye yes thats strange. but may be OP miss typed or forgot to update the question as he was getting data in database.

Answer (score 0):

Your `hof_id=>$last_id` is fixed. it needs to increment with every iteration if it is primary or unique key in your database.

Comment: no problem on capturing all data from array. the issue is only the first character of each data element was saved on the table. (**W** only for **Wafer**)